# Referência de Objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto ao tentar recuperar um elemento num arquivo XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Estou com um erro me atormentando.

Basicamente estou salvando as configurações de todos equipamentos(Leitores de RF) num arquivo XML(Configs.xml). Meu objetivo é recuperar o primeiro elemento dentre todas as configurações que tenha um valor "setado"(diferente de "") no atributo novoLote. Caso o elemento recuperado seja diferente de null eu prossigo com o código dentro do IF, caso contrário eu lançarei uma exceção. Contudo, o código abaixo dá o seguinte erro quando estou tentando recuperar o elemento(terceira linha): Referência de Objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Alguém pode me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado? Valeu!

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load("Configs.xml");
XElement x = null;
x = xml.Elements().Where(p => !p.Attribute("novoLote").Value.Equals("")).FirstOrDefault();
if (x != null)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    throw new ReaderNaoConfiguradoParaFuncaoException("Nenhum Reader está configurado para essa função.");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto pode ser simplificado para:

```
x = xml.Elements().FirstOrDefault(p => !p.Attribute("novoLote").Value.Equals(""));
```

Ainda assim, é propenso a erros. Você pode melhorar a sentença para:

```
x = xml.Elements().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Attribute("novoLote").Value != null && !p.Attribute("novoLote").Value.Equals(""))
```

Comment: Olá Cigano, infelizmente não funcionou as duas opções que você falou. Ambas dão o mesmo erro informado na minha pergunta. :(

Comment: Coloque um *breakpoint* na linha e verifique qual dos elementos é nulo.

Comment: Apenas o x é null.

Comment: O valor armazenado em xml é o seguinte:

<configs>
  <reader port="23" ip="192.168.8.3" login="alien" senha="password" antennaSequence="0,1" power="0" tagListFormat="Custom" customFormat="TagID: ${TAGIDW} TX: ${TX} SPEED: ${SPEED}" type="alienConfig" speedFilter="0.25, -0.25" autoMode="OFF" mac="00:1B:5F:00:4E:9F" novoLote="1" contaminacao="" mudancaFase="" descarte="" />
</configs>

Comment: `xml.Elements().First().Attribute("novoLote")` devolve nulo?

Comment: Não, Ele devolve isso para x:

<reader port="23" ip="192.168.8.3" login="alien" senha="password" antennaSequence="0,1" power="0" tagListFormat="Custom" customFormat="TagID: ${TAGIDW} TX: ${TX} SPEED: ${SPEED}" type="alienConfig" speedFilter="0.25, -0.25" autoMode="OFF" mac="00:1B:5F:00:4E:9F" novoLote="1" contaminacao="" mudancaFase="" descarte="" />

Comment: Veja que minha pergunta foi outra. Minha dúvida é o que está sendo nulo, não o que é devolvido para x, tanto que pedi um outro teste no código, conforme coloquei acima. Pode fazer este teste, por favor?

Comment: Fiz assim Cigano: XAttribute a = xml.Elements().First().Attribute("novoLote");
E devolveu: {novoLote="1"}

Comment: Esquisito. Tem algo nulo mesmo, mas não sei te dizer o que é, já que o teste devolveu um elemento.

Comment: Olá Cigano, consegui resolver. Seu código ajudou muito. Foi um pequeno detalhe que mudei e funcionou aqui. Segue a resolução:
x = xml.Elements().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Attribute("novoLote").Value != null && !p.Attribute("novoLote").Value.Equals(""));

Eu adicionei o .Value na comparação para ver se era diferente de null.

Comment: Obrigado! Atualizei a resposta.